# Как заполнить margin left и right у изображения этим же заблюренным изображением?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Хочу сделать эффект, как на скриншоте, чтобы при изменении ширины margin отцентрованного изображения заполнялся его же заблюренной версией.

Разумеется можно сделать через background контейнера, но хотелось бы найти JS библиотеку для такого. Подскажите название, если такая существует и как название эффекта, если есть устоявшееся.

Решение на обычном JS тоже подойдёт

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: так и зачем пилить js-библиотеку, если можно сделать двумя строчками css ?

Comment: Какими? Я сюда вроде за помощью пришёл, решениям, которые не вижу сам рад вдвойне

Comment: ну так сами написали, что фоном контейнера.

Comment: Изображения будут меняться через CMS, а выносить CSS в теги не особо хочется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как-то так пойдет,  или нет? Можно, конечно, обернуть картинку во враппер и на лету, но смысла в этом не вижу. да и в целом, bg даже лучше в верстку вставить, меняя только урл фона

```js
$(".blur-image").each(function(){
   let src = $(this).attr('src')
   let bg = $('<div class="blur-img-bg">').css('background-image', `url(${src})`);
   $(this).closest(".blur-img-wrapper").prepend(bg); 
          
});
```

```css
.blur-img-wrapper {       
   position: relative;   
   text-align: center;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.blur-img-bg {  
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  right: -5px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;   
  filter: blur(5px);
  z-index: -1;
}

.blur-image {
  max-width: 50%;
  margin: 0px 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="blur-img-wrapper">
  <img class="blur-image" src="https://img.volcanodiscovery.com/fileadmin/photos/user/tompfeiffer/bromo_i43213.jpg"/>
</div>
```

То есть варианты - делаем изначально структуру

```
.wrapper
    .bg
    img
```

и только устаналвиаем стиль background-image

либо еще в целом изначально имеем `img` и  делаем wrap и добавление bg как в примере.